# Choose driver as target in Hardware Certification Tool API

Tags: c#, drivers

How can I choise driver as target in HCK API? For example, I need to test `NULL.SYS` via HCK API. In HCK Studio, I need to check in software devices: `NULL.SYS`. 
[image]How can I do this via code? I tryed:

```
        Project project = manager.CreateProject(projectName);
        //
        OSPlatform platform = testPool.GetMachines().First().OSPlatform;
        ProductInstance pi = project.CreateProductInstance(platform.Name, testPool, platform);
        var targets = pi.GetMachines();

        ReadOnlyCollection<TargetData> data = pi.FindTargetFromId(@"NULL.SYS");
```

but, after this data count is 0. What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API if you have a Hardware ID for your driver. 
Go to device manager and find the HID.

If your driver is a non PNP driver, it is a little tricky to use the API. 
I am also trying to figure out the Target class 
For eg. The HCK tool enumerates the drivers using TargetType.Filter for Filter drivers (which are under softare devices)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Machine.GetTestTargets()** or **Machine.GetTestTargets(TargetType.Filter)**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/api/machinegettesttargets-method--targettype-